# Issues using an array created by getElementsbyClassName in a for loop

Tags: javascript, getelementsbyclassname

I am trying to call a set of elements from an HTML doc by class name, which I understand returns them as an array-like object. I would like to cycle through the values of this array in a for loop, but the loop is returning 'undefined' for every value in the array, even though there is definitely a value in the elements that I am calling.

I basically want to output the following onto the web page, into some simple div elements:

Age prediction line 1: Hello George, you are 28 in 2019

Age prediction line 2: Hello Andy, you are 29 in 2020

Age prediction line 3: Hello Kyle, you are 30 in 2021

Age prediction line 4: Hello Jenny, you are 31 in 2022

The names are the values of the elements in the "myinput" class. I am using a pretty standard for loop as below:

```
const years = [2019, 2020, 2021, 2022];

var name = document.getElementsByClassName("myinput");
var age = document.getElementById("agefield").value;

var intage = parseInt(age, 10);

for (i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
  document.getElementsByClassName("ageprediction")[i].innerHTML = "Age 
  prediction line " + (i+1) + ": ";
  document.getElementsByClassName("testdiv")[i].innerHTML = " Hello " + 
  name[i].value + " you are " + [intage+i] + " in " + years[i];
}
```

There is just one agefield element, and calling that by Id, adding.value and converting to an integer works fine. But after understanding and reading everywhere that you could use code like this to cycle through the elements of a getElementbyClass array in a for loop using the current index value, I am still getting 'undefined' as the result. Is this because name[i].value is not the correct code?

UPDATE: A couple of people asked to see the relevant HTML as well, here it is:

```
<section id="form">

  <input class="myinput" value="George"/><br/><br/>
  <input class="myinput" value="Andy"/><br/><br/>
  <input class="myinput" value="Kyle"/><br/><br/>
  <input class="myinput" value="Jenny"/><br/><br/>

  <input id="agefield" placeholder="Your age" value="28"/><br/><br/>

  <div class ="ageprediction"></div><div class = "testdiv">Testing</div><br/><br/>
  <div class ="ageprediction"></div><div class = "testdiv">Testing</div><br/><br/>
  <div class ="ageprediction"></div><div class = "testdiv">Testing</div><br/><br/>
  <div class ="ageprediction"></div><div class = "testdiv">Testing</div><br/><br/>

</section>
```

As you can see, I'm just using predefined values in the inputs for now for testing purposes.

Comment: How many elements are in the name object?

Comment: where do you have undefined ?

Comment: Could you add html code to your question.

Comment: Hi all, I have just added the relevant HTML above. I hope that helps and sorry for not including it the first time around.

Comment: That's not normal, your code is correct. After tested it, I get the same issue (`document.getElementsByClassName` is directly converted to string). However, I corrected the problem by switching `var name` to `let name`... But that seems to happen only on SE Overflow, because I can't reproduce the issue on [jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/d938yowa/).

Comment: Thanks a lot - seems to be what others have said, variables can't be called name, or at least not int he editor I am using! Thanks for looking into it.

Answer (score 0):

It is actually works. Check out this link : [https://jsfiddle.net/dy0feLha](https://jsfiddle.net/dy0feLha/)

```
const years = [2019, 2020, 2021, 2022];

var name = document.getElementsByClassName("myinput");
var age = document.getElementById("agefield").value;

var intage = parseInt(age, 10);

for (i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
  document.getElementsByClassName("ageprediction")[i].innerHTML = "Age prediction line " + (i+1) + ": ";
  document.getElementsByClassName("testdiv")[i].innerHTML = " Hello " + 
  name[i].value + " you are " + [intage+i] + " in " + years[i];
}
```

I simply just changed first line in the loop. It has to be in the same line. But it maybe already same in your code editor.

Comment: Thanks - for some reason the variable being called name seemed to be causing issues! Thanks for looking into it

Answer (score 0):

You can't affect content to a variable named "name", the content will be automatically converted to string :

> window.name will convert all values to their string representations by
>   using the toString method.

[From developer.mozilla](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/name)

It works if you simply rename the variable

```js
const years = [2019, 2020, 2021, 2022];
 
  var names = document.getElementsByClassName("myinput");
 console.log(names);
 var age = document.getElementById("agefield").value;

 var intage = parseInt(age, 10);

 for (i = 0; i < 4; i++) {

   document.getElementsByClassName("ageprediction")[i].innerHTML = "Age prediction line " + (i+1) + ": ";
   document.getElementsByClassName("testdiv")[i].innerHTML = " Hello " + names[i].value + " you are " + [intage+i] + " in " + years[i];
 }
```

```html
<section id="form">

  <input class="myinput" value="George"/><br/><br/>
  <input class="myinput" value="Andy"/><br/><br/>
  <input class="myinput" value="Kyle"/><br/><br/>
  <input class="myinput" value="Jenny"/><br/><br/>

  <input id="agefield" placeholder="Your age" value="28"/><br/><br/>

  <div class ="ageprediction"></div><div class = "testdiv">Testing</div><br/><br/>
  <div class ="ageprediction"></div><div class = "testdiv">Testing</div><br/><br/>
  <div class ="ageprediction"></div><div class = "testdiv">Testing</div><br/><br/>
  <div class ="ageprediction"></div><div class = "testdiv">Testing</div><br/><br/>

</section>
```

Comment: Thanks - yes, for some reason the variable being called name seemed to be causing issues! this solved it, thanks for your help